# Unable to Send @ Character in SMS via GSM Modem (nokia C1-02)

Tags: encoding, vb6, sms, gsm, modem

I have a VB6 Application to send SMS.  The problem is that I am unable to send `@` character.

For example if I write in computer `ayaz.haider@yahoo.com` it sends `ayaz.haider¡yahoo.com`

FOLLOWING IS TERMINAL LOG:

```
AT+CSCS=?
+CSCS: ("UCS2","GSM","PCCP437","PCDN","IRA","8859-1","HEX","UTF-8")

OK
AT+CSCS="UCS2"
OK
AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "UCS2"

OK
AT+CS
ERROR
AT+CMGS="03433091454"
> AYAZ.HAIDER@YAHOO.COM
> 
+CMGS: 55

OK
```

Terminal Window:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code from the VB6 app?

Comment: This is only a guess, but try replacing the `@` with `%40`. See [here](https://www.smsmode.com/en/les-caracteres-acceptes-pour-lenvoi-de-vos-sms/) for reference.

Comment: if I send `ASCII Code chr(40)`  then it show **(** and if I send  `ayaz.haider%40yahoo.com` then it Show same **ayaz.haider%40.com** . can you please let me know how to send this Code ??

Comment: I found solution by sending all `ASCII Codes Chr(1) to Chr(255)` and `chr(128)` Show **@** . Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @AyazHaider Glad you worked it out. You should add an answer below with details of your solution - that could help someone else in the future.